# SQL problema para sumar filas SQL SERVER

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server

Necesito sumar los sueldos de la siguiente consulta que tengo y ordenarlos por la descripción.

```
select distinct 

    cp.descripcion,
    cp.idSysCPPuestos,
    em.sueldoDiario,
    em.sueldoIntegrado,
    em.idSysCPCentroCosto
    --,sum(CAST(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4)))+sum(CAST(em.sueldoIntegrado AS DECIMAL(18, 4)))



from 
sysCPEmpleados ce 

    inner join  sysCPCentroCosto cc on 
    ce.idSysCPCentroCosto = cc.idSysCPCentroCosto and
    ce.idSysCPEmpresas = cc.idSysCPEmpresas
    inner join sysCPEmpleados em on
    em.idSysCPEmpresas = cc.idSysCPEmpresas
    inner join sysCPPuestos cp on
    em.idSysCPPuestos = cp.idSysCPPuestos

    where cc.idSysCPCentroCosto = 'y'
    and em.idSysCPEmpresas = 'x'
```

esto es lo que tengo y lo que me devuelve
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]
hasta aquí todo bien,
pero si intento hacer la suma comentada me devuelve lo sigueinte

> Column 'sysCPPuestos.descripcion' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.

Alguien podría instruirme como hacer de manera correcta esta operación, lo que necesito es sumar las cantidades donde la descripción de **cc.descripcion** sea la misma. Mil gracias.

Comment: Es que te falta el `GROUP BY`. ¿Que columnas tienes que sumar?

Comment: @PatricioMoracho No, si le doy group by me lo sig ** Column 'sysCPPuestos.descripcion' is invalid in the select list because it is not contained in either an aggregate function or the GROUP BY clause.
 ** y aún con la suma comentada / estas em.sueldoDiario y em.sueldoIntegrado

Answer (score 1):

Siempre que hagas un `columna1, sum(columna2)` tendrás que añadir la clausula `group by columna1`

> Devuelve la suma de todos los valores o solo de los valores DISTINCT de la expresión. SUM solo puede utilizarse con columnas numéricas. Se omiten los valores NULL.

Mas info en [SUM (Transact-SQL)](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/sql/t-sql/functions/sum-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)

```
select distinct 

    cp.descripcion,
    cp.idSysCPPuestos,
    em.sueldoDiario,
    em.sueldoIntegrado,
    em.idSysCPCentroCosto,
    sum(CAST(em.sueldoDiario AS DECIMAL(18, 4)))+sum(CAST(em.sueldoIntegrado AS DECIMAL(18, 4)))

from 
sysCPEmpleados ce 

    inner join  sysCPCentroCosto cc on 
       ce.idSysCPCentroCosto = cc.idSysCPCentroCosto and
       ce.idSysCPEmpresas = cc.idSysCPEmpresas
    inner join sysCPEmpleados em on
       em.idSysCPEmpresas = cc.idSysCPEmpresas
    inner join sysCPPuestos cp on
       em.idSysCPPuestos = cp.idSysCPPuestos

    where cc.idSysCPCentroCosto = 'y'
       and em.idSysCPEmpresas = 'x'
    group by cp.descripcion,
       cp.idSysCPPuestos,
       em.sueldoDiario,
       em.sueldoIntegrado,
       em.idSysCPCentroCosto;
```

Comment: @rencias eres un sabio ;D pero hace falta ordenarlos por descripcion la descripcion se sigue reptiendo

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim mi respuesta es una pequeña versión algo extendida de lo que ha puesto el compañero [Patricio Moracho](https://es.stackoverflow.com/users/31764/patricio-moracho)

Comment: @E.Rawrdríguez.Ophanim Pero que quieres, ordenarlos por descripción o agruparlos solo por descripción y que calcules los totales de cada descripción?

Comment: la suma esta bien pero necesito agruparlos por descripcion = ** analista de control | 200 ** por ejemplo

Comment: Entonces para que sacas el resto de los campos? cp.idSysCPPuestos y em.idSysCPCentroCosto. También añado que con todos los datos ocultos dificulta entender lo que pides.